# Matplotlib defaulting to fivethirtyeight style sheet

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm graphing some data in matplotlib, and for some reason, even without including

```
matplotlib.pyplot.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

I still end up with fivethirtyeight-style graphs. Fivethirtyeight was one of the first style sheets I tried, but now I can't seem to get rid of it without using another style sheet, when what I'd really like to do is start with the matplotlib default settings and customize them myself.

Is there a setting somewhere that I'm missing or some file I need to edit?

Comment: did you restart the interactive session?

Comment: In case anyone needs the reverse i.e. default style as `fivethirtyeight`, you can simply add `style.use("fivethirtyeight")` line somewhere in the `pyplot.py` file in the matplotlib package directory.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your matplotlibrc settings. You can locate the file by doing:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()
'/home/foo/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc'
```

Otherwise also check:

```
`~/.matplotlib/stylelib`
```

May be you overwrote the default. Finally you can always do:

```
plt.rcdefaults()
```

for a temporary solution. The permanent equivalent would be to delete your `.matplotlib` folder.